# Can a Swift enum be referenced as a variable?

Tags: swift, enums

I am centralizing all my application strings in enums, and these strings are all namespaced to the application feature in which they are used (example below).

When I attempt to store the enum in a variable (like `var strings = Strings.Feature.SubFeature`) and call it like `strings.someStringValue`, I get a `Expected member name or constructor call after name type` error.

**Declaration:**

```
enum Strings {
     enum Feature {
          enum Subfeature {
               static var someString: String { "some string".localizedLowerCase }
          }
     }
}
```

**Callsite:**

```
someLabel.text = Strings.Feature.Subfeature.string
```

Hoped-for behavior:

```
var strings = Strings.Feature.Subfeature
someLabel.text = strings.someString
```

Is it possible to store a reference to the containing enum, such that I will not have to reference the full path every time I use a given string? I would love to know if there are any alternative ways of going about this as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Joakim's answer looks like it answers your question, but another option (with potentially lower memory use?) would be using a typealias.

```
typealias SubFeatureStrings = Strings.Feature.Subfeature
```

and then

```
SubFeatureStrings.someString
```

The typealias could be nested inside the class/struct where you're calling it, to avoid conflicts across your app.

Comment: I like this alternative too and I guess it depends on the scope which one is best to use.

Comment: type aliases can even be local to any scope, like that of a function. Really handy for when I repeat constants from the same type a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
enum Strings {
    enum Feature {
        enum Subfeature {
            static var someString: String { "some string".localizedLowerCase }
            static var otherString: String { "some other string".localizedLowerCase }
        }
    }
}

var strings = Strings.Feature.Subfeature.self
someLabel.text = strings.someString
someLabel.text = strings.someOtherString
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this was possible. Cool!

Answer (score 0):

An enum can be `enum <#name#> : String`

```swift
enum Foo : String {
    case bar = "bar"
}
```

usage: `<#something#>.text = Foo.bar.rawValue`

---

For chained purposes

```swift
enum SomeEnum {
    enum Foo : String {
        case bar = "bar"
    }
}
```

usage: `<#something#>.text = SomeEnum.Foo.bar.rawValue`

---

Then you can typealias the chain:

```swift
typealias foo = SomeEnum.Foo
<#something#>.text = foo.bar.rawValue
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Enums are Type in Swift.